# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest' in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pytest, python-module

I am new to python and trying to run code from existing project. I am getting the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxxx/xxxx/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pytest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
```

The file is present in the mentioned path.
I see that there are many questions regarding this but nothing seems to provide me with a solution.
I am using the IntelliJ IDEA IDE.

Comment: does your python environment have `pytest` installed? you can install it using `pip install pytest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `File "/xxxx/xxxx/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2021.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py"` is trying to import `pytest` but fails to find the package. That is, it's not the presence of that file that's failing, but that it can't find `pytest` in order to import it.

Install `pytest` using

```
python3 -m pip install pytest
```

Change `python3` accordingly to use the specific installation of python that you're using in the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/9007972337682-No-module-named-pytest-within-PyCharm-works-in-Python-CLI-) worked for me. Repeating here:

- Open IntelliJ's settings/preferences
- Go to **Tools** -> **Python Integrated Tools**
- Under **Testing**...*Default test runner:* choose **pytest**
- Click the **Fix** button that appears in the bottom of the panel

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have the needed environment.
Since you use the Pycharm, you can try to install pytest.
https://blog.finxter.com/how-to-install-a-library-on-pycharm/

Answer (score 0):

If the project uses poetry for dependency management, there is an IJ bug where it does not recognize group dependencies. If pytest is listed as a group dev dependency you will have the same error you mentioned.

Bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-55968/Support-Poetry-1.2-dependency-groups

If this is your problem, running tests from the command line will still work (poetry run pytest ...), or you could add pytest to the main dependency group to your pyproject.toml (tool.poetry.dependencies).